# In Loopback 4, wow to hide {"additionalProp1": {}} from Swagger Explorer?

Tags: mongodb, swagger, loopback

I have created Loopback Rest API application using MongoDB. When I run the Swagger Explore in most of endpoints am seeing **"additionalProp1": {}**.

Is there any way to hide this in Swagger?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it by changing the model settings to "strict".

Change the Model to:

```
@model({settings: {
  strict: true,
}
})
export class YourModel extends Entity {
```